# Resend an image automatically

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I would like to make sure that if I send a picture my bot will send it back immediately afterwards in the same channel. Could you help me?

Thank you very much in advance for the help you will give me.

Comment: You need to show how you tried to get this to work.

Comment: Please show some code.  Good that you tagged the tech - but we need to see code in order to provide a better answer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here questions normally need to have all the steps of "What have you tried?" included.

 I'd recommend you search how to get the URL for the image that got sent, and how to embed an image into a message. Once you've tried, if you still have problems come ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### v13

```js
const {Client} = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client()

client.on('messageCreate', ({attachments, author, channel}) => {
  // don't reply to bots
  if (author.bot) return

  // sends the first attachment if there are any
  if (attachments.size) channel.send({files: [attachments.first()]})
})
```

### v12

```js
const {Client} = require('discord.js')

const client = new Client()

client.on('message', ({attachments, author, channel}) => {
  // don't reply to bots
  if (author.bot) return

  // sends the first attachment if there are any
  if (attachments.size) channel.send(attachments.first())
})
```

Comment: The code returns error, do I change the syntax?
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Comment: @FabrizioPiminchumo I added a version for discord.js v13 to my answer. Try that.